# Users from old windows installation in my fresh install's registry

Tags: windows-7, windows

I noticed something strange, HKEY_USERS contains folders for all the user accounts from my previous windows installation.

I did a fresh win 7 install just a few days ago on a new hard drive, all though, the old hard drive is connected since I'm still in the process of going through all my stuff and copying over the necessary before I wipe it.

While installing my current windows though, I had all other drives disconnected to avoid some quirks courtesy of my motherboard, I have not booted the old windows installation since I moved to the new one.

So how can this be? How did those folders end up there? Can I delete them?

EDIT: All the users from my old installation in the new registry follow this pattern:

RK_username_ON_D_xxxx where xxxx is a seemingly random 4 digit hexadecimal string

I also found some of this in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, such as "RK_Software_ON_D_xxxx"

Comment: Do the user profiles actually exist?

Comment: On the new installation? No

Comment: Your new installation knows about your other installation because both disks are connected.  What you discovered is perfectly normal.

Comment: @Ramhound okay but once I wipe the old drive, can I delete them?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. There a reason you want to?

Comment: @ramhound well yea, the old installation was REALLY old, years and years, caught a few viruses along the way and cleaned but it ended up permanently modified in some odd ways and I have a sneaking suspicion that there still might have been a few lurking around even though I threw every antivirus on the planet at it. Essentially I'd like to have as little of it in my new installation as possible, preferably none at all.

Comment: What you discovered is harmless

Comment: I've never heard of a truly clean, new install of Windows enumerating users from another installation visible on the machine. I don't buy that as being normal. Are you *sure* you did a **clean** install?

Comment: @Twisty yea, I'm pretty sure. I also found out what it was, the deep scan tool from malwarebytes temporarily mounts the registry hives from any windows installation it finds in the currently running registry with the RK_*_ON_xxxx prefix and postfix. I guess its so that people can scan for malware while not booted into that installation of windows.

Comment: In light of your discovery that MBAM mounted those user registry hives, I retract my concern that you didn't perform a clean Windows install.  So yes, it's safe to delete those user keys.  You should post a self-answer for this!